# python -m SimpleHttpServer [port] on OSX

Tags: python, html, macos, simplehttpserver

I created simplest html page

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello, world.
    </body>
</html>
```

and run `python -m SimpleHTTPServe 8000` in the page's folder.

**Problem:** When I go to `localhost:8000` I see the text of my page. Means the http server instead of interpreting it as html page wraps each string of my page into `<p>` tag.

If I open sources I get:

```
<html> 
........
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;</span><b>html</b><span class="s2"> </span><span class="s3">lang</span><span class="s1">=</span><span class="s4">"en"</span><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2">    <span class="s1">&lt;</span><span class="s5"><b>head</b></span><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2">        <span class="s1">&lt;</span><span class="s5"><b>meta</b></span> <span class="s3">charset</span><span class="s1">=</span><span class="s4">"utf-8"</span><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p3"><span class="s2">        </span>&lt;<span class="s5"><b>title</b></span>&gt;Backbone.js Todo App&lt;/<span class="s5"><b>title</b></span>&gt;</p>
<p class="p2">    <span class="s1">&lt;/</span><span class="s5"><b>head</b></span><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p2">    <span class="s1">&lt;</span><span class="s5"><b>body</b></span><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
<p class="p3"><span class="s2">        </span>Hello, world.</p>
<p class="p3"><span class="Apple-converted-space">    </span>&lt;/<span class="s5"><b>body</b></span>&gt;</p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">&lt;/</span><b>html</b><span class="s1">&gt;</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the filename of your page?

Answer (score 1):

If you're editing your page in TextEdit, make sure you open the Format menu and choose "Make Plain Text."

[image: Plain Text]

If you saved as HTML without this option, TextEdit would have added those tags to keep your text file's formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried on my mac and I don't observe similar behaviour: I start server slightly differently:

- `python -mSimpleHTTPServer 8000` : no space between m and SimpleHTTPServer (checked with space, same behaviour)
- I have 2 files : a.out and a.html with same content : it looks like a.out gets downloaded while a.html gets displayed (with chrome)

My guess is that your file has no extension .html and that your browser itself is adding the tags to display it.

You can try downloading the file with curl to make sure : `curl http://localhost:8000/a.out` from a terminal

Note : I'm running MacOS 10.9.4 on a McBook air with python 2.7.5

Comment: my bad, I used default text editor, which past a lot of formatting symbols

Answer (score 0):

If your page show up as text just as you are describing then that most likely means that the server does not use the correct `content-type` in its HTTP headers.  `SimpleHTTPServer` uses the module `mimetypes` to determine what `content-type` to use for most file types.

You can check it yourself:

```
>>> import mimetypes
>>> mimetypes.init()
>>> print mimetypes.types_map
...
```

or more specifically

```
>>> print mimetypes.types_map['.html']
text/html
```

Make sure your file extension matches with what `mimetypes` expects.

Comment: Try them out directly in your python interpreter. That is, start `python` and paste them in.

Comment: my bad, I used default text editor, which past a lot of formatting symbols